# Making a dropdown allow more than one option to be chosen

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out how to use HTML5 to create a drop down that will be populated from a database but that will display like the image below. I am trying to be able to either select a few locations or have a button that selects many or remove all if any while showing the customer in another dropdown or text area what was chosen having a way to remove single items as well. Do you have to use Javascript in order to make these functions work or is it at all possible to just do this using HTML5?

[image]

```
<form name="generatereport" method="post" action="?_location_queries.cfm">

<select name="Location" id="loc" multiple="multiple">
    <!---<option selected value="">Select location</option>--->
    <option value="OPERATIONS">Operations</option>
    <option value="CCC">Contact Center</option>
    <option value="QA">QA Department</option>
    <option value="DS">DeSoto</option>
    <option value="PS">Palma Sola</option>
    <option value="LWR">Lakewood Ranch</option>
    <option value="NR">North River</option>
    <option value="SDL">SDL</option>
</select>

<button id="add">ADD ALL</button>
<button id="rem">REMOVE ALL</button>
<br /><br />

<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Continue" />

</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
var opts = document.querySelectorAll('#loc option');

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        opts[i].selected = true;
    }
});

document.getElementById('rem').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        opts[i].selected = false;
    }
}); 
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m26kru2w/

Comment: You'd just add the `multiple="multiple"` attribute to the select, and you'd need javascript to make the buttons work. A Google search should tell you how.

Comment: It's quite straight forward -> https://jsfiddle.net/m26kru2w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, forked from @adeneo's example:

```js
var opts = document.querySelectorAll('#loc option');

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
 for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
     opts[i].selected = true;
    }
    
    reflectChange();
});

document.getElementById('rem').addEventListener('click', function() {
 for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
     opts[i].selected = false;
    }
    
    reflectChange();
});

document.getElementById('loc').addEventListener('change', reflectChange);

function reflectChange() {
 document.getElementById('selected').value = '';
  
 for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
     if(opts[i].selected)
       document.getElementById('selected').value += opts[i].text+'\n';
    }
}
```

```html
<select name="Location" id="loc" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="all">All Departments</option>
    <option value="OPERATIONS">Operations</option>
    <option value="CCC">Contact Center</option>
    <option value="QA">QA Department</option>
    <option value="DS">DeSoto</option>
    <option value="PS">Palma Sola</option>
    <option value="LWR">Lakewood Ranch</option>
    <option value="NR">North River</option>
    <option value="SDL">SDL</option>
</select>

<button id="add">ADD ALL</button>
<button id="rem">REMOVE ALL</button>

<textarea id="selected"></textarea>
```